# javascript if condition trouble

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write this condition in javascript:

```
if(window.location.pathname != '/our-communities.php' && (window.location.pathname == '/upcoming-communities.php' && window.location.search != '')){
```

What I am trying to say is if the page is not our-communities.php and if the page is not upcoming-communities.php and window.location.search is not blank then run the code.

So this condition should run on every page except for our-communities.php but can run on upcoming-communities.php only if window.location.search is blank.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.location.pathname != "/our-communities.php" || (window.location.pathname == "/upcoming-communities.php" && window.location.search == "")) {

}
```

One thing to note, if the page is `"/upcoming-communities.php"` then the first condition will always be true meaning the second OR statement is irrelevant, if you want to enforce that then extra conditionals are needed.

```
if ((window.location.pathname != "/our-communities.php" && window.location.pathname != "/upcoming-communities.php") || (window.location.pathname == "/upcoming-communities.php" && window.location.search == "")) {

}
```

Comment: This does not work...when I am in upcoming-communities.php and window.location.search is not blank, the code gets run, it should not. It should run only on upcoming-communities.php when window.location.search is blank.

Comment: Please accept as the answer if it was correct so it can help other users